# How to solve `neo4j: command not found` error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, neo4j

I followed the steps on [debian - stable installation instructions](http://www.neo4j.org/download/linux) verbatim.

However, when I run the last step I get:

```
cammil@cammil-desktop:~$ neo4j start
neo4j: command not found
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Are you sure that `apt-get install neo4j` was successful?

Comment: Well, http://localhost:7474 is running a gui, and I've added some nodes and relationships (not really sure what I'm doing yet though).

Answer (score 5):

You can start the neo4j server with:

```
service neo4j-service start
```

But, if you are able to access localhost:7474, then the server has already been started. You can check the status with:

```
service neo4j-service status
```

Or if you want to stop it:

```
service neo4j-service stop
```

Comment: Run as the `neo4j` user: `sudo -u neo4j service neo4j-service start`

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have . in your PATH, so you need to do ./neo4j start.
From [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18114890/got-neo4j-command-not-found-error-when-installing-neo4j-on-linux-machine)