# Got "neo4j: command not found" error when installing Neo4j on Linux machine

Tags: linux, neo4j

I tried to install Neo4j1.9.2 on an Ubuntu machine. I downloaded neo4j-community-1.9.2-unix.tar.gz from Neo4j.org and unzipped it. The neo4j file is in the bin directory.

In bin directory, I typed command "neo4j start", got error "neo4j: command not found". I also tried command "sudo neo4j install", after I provided the password, I got same error "neo4j: command not found".

Java has been installed on this machine: 
java version "1.6.0_27"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.5) (6b27-1.12.5-0ubuntu0.12.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably don't have `.` in your `PATH`, so you need to do `./neo4j start`.

Answer (score 1):

If you install neo4j on your system using a package manager (mine is on gentoo using the portage overlay) the command is under `/etc/init.d/neo4j`. I found these useful in gentoo.

```
rc-service neo4j start
rc-update add neo4j default
```

The shell is on the path for all users, but the service is not on the path. This is the case for most services in most linux distributions, unless you have a DIY install.

Answer (score 0):

You can start the neo4j server with:

`service neo4j-service start`

But, if you are able to access localhost:7474, then the server has already been started. You can check the status with:

`service neo4j-service status`